# Let's not be [argumentative]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, burninate-request

The tag [argumentative](/questions/tagged/argumentative) seems to be another tag with little use and no clear purpose. Some of the nine current uses are along with [subjective](/questions/tagged/subjective) where the question refers to the old "subjective and argumentative" close reason (later replaced retroactively with "not constructive", which was later removed). Others refer to user conduct.

Shall we argue to remove it?

Comment: I’d say retag to behavior and not-constructive, maybe merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were five questions using the tag as of earlier today (of which two were below -8 score), and I just went and removed it from all of them.

Of those, I mostly retagged to [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior), and in the one case where it referred to the old "subjective and argumentative" close reason, I instead also removed [subjective](/questions/tagged/subjective) and replaced both with [not-constructive](/questions/tagged/not-constructive) (what "subjective and argumentative" was later renamed to).

Thus, this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Answer (score 6):

I argue that we need to do some retagging, not burnination.

There are 9 questions with the [argumentative](/questions/tagged/argumentative) tag. Of those:

- 4 questions are tagged with both [argumentative](/questions/tagged/argumentative) and [subjective](/questions/tagged/subjective), and refer to the former "subjective and argumentative" close reason. These could possibly be retagged to [not-constructive](/questions/tagged/not-constructive) as @MEE suggested.
- 5 questions refer to users' behavior. In this case, they should be retagged to [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior).

Comment: I'd say retag to [tag:behavior] if needed and then synonymize/merge to [tag:not-constructive]